# Parsing XML and ignoring sections with powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to parse out the key fields and Data table information from here with PowerShell.

I only want the datatable name if there is a keyfield so in the example below I do not want CC:Attribute.

I also want to output things to a text file.

I want to have a text file that is created that holds the Data table name & Access as well as all the key fields and what they are.

This is the code I have so far:

```
[xml]$global:xmldata = get-content "C:\hackathon\Mfg.xml"

$xmldata2 = $xmldata.SchemaPackage.Tables


$SField = $xmldata2.DataTable.KeyFields | %{$_.StringField} 
$Reffield = $xmldata2.DataTable.KeyFields | %{$_.ReferenceField} 
$table = $xmldata2 | %{$_.DataTable}
```

Xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SchemaPackage Namespace="Mfg" xmlns="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <DataTable Name="CC::Attribute">
        <DataFields>
        </DataFields>
    </DataTable>

    <DataTable Name="PlannerCode" Access="WW">
        <Licenses>Manufacturing, DemandManagement</Licenses>
        <Flags>
        </Flags>
        <KeyFields>
            <StringField Name="Value"/>
            <ReferenceField Name="Site" Target="Core::Site" SetField="PlannerCodes"/>
        </KeyFields>
        <DataFields>
            <StringField Name="Description"/>
        </DataFields>
    </DataTable>
</SchemaPackage>
```

Comment: Hi Brendan, and welcome to StackOverflow! Your xml sample seems to be broken and/or incomplete (the root node `<SchemaPackage>` start tag is unclosed and no matching end tag exists). Please update the post

Comment: I have done so. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Despite the edit you made, I can only get your XML to validate if I modify it slightly (cleaning the opening XML tag and removing the `SchemaPackage` namespace). Regardless,
if you're experiencing no issues with your XML import then it's fine.

Here I'm just constructing the XML object from a [herestring](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/12/31/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) because I haven't got it in a file on disk.

```
[xml]$xmldata = @"
<xml>
    <DataTable Name="CC::Attribute">
        <DataFields>
        </DataFields>
    </DataTable>
    <DataTable Name="PlannerCode">
        <Licenses>Manufacturing, DemandManagement</Licenses>
        <Flags>
        </Flags>
        <KeyFields>
            <StringField Name="Value"/>
            <ReferenceField Name="Site" Target="Core::Site" SetField="PlannerCodes"/>
        </KeyFields>
        <DataFields>
            <StringField Name="Description"/>
        </DataFields>
    </DataTable>
</xml>
"@

# Filter DataTable nodes for those with a KeyFields child node.
$DataTablesWithKeyFields = $xmldata.xml.DataTable | Where-Object { $_.KeyFields }

$DataTableName = $DataTablesWithKeyFields.Name
$StringFieldData = $DataTablesWithKeyFields.KeyFields.ReferenceField
$ReferenceFieldData = $DataTablesWithKeyFields.KeyFields.ReferenceField
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're after. `$DataTablesWithKeyFields` could be an array depending on your XML file so you may need to loop it to extract the information you require.

Comment: Thanks. I think you have helped me out here.

Comment: HI Robin, This is a big improvement and it works until a record is found with multiple Reference or String fields. Any thoughts here?

Comment: @Brendan If's not clear what you meant by 'a record'. Do you mean to say that if your XML has **additional** DataTable nodes with KeyFields childnodes? If this is the case then please see the note about `$DataTablesWithKeyFields` being an array object and looping the result.

Comment: HI Robin. Thanks for getting back your help is appreciated. I updated the question to make it more clear. The objectiveis to create a text file that has all the Datatable names as well as their key fields and what they are. Some keyfields have more data than others so it is difficult to format the text file properly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're working with XML, one of the querying options is XPath!

You can select only `DataTable` nodes that have a `KeyFields` child with the following XPath expression:

```
/SchemaPackage/DataTable[KeyFields]
```

You can use `Select-Xml`:

```
Select-Xml -Path C:\hackathon\Mfg.xml -XPath /SchemaPackage/DataTable[KeyFields] |Select-Object -Expand Node
```

or pass the expression as an argument to the `SelectSingleNodes()` method:

```
[xml]$xmldata = Get-Content C:\hackathon\Mfg.xml
$xmldata.SelectNodes('/SchemaPackage/DataTable[KeyFields]')
```